# How to get "proportion of variance" vector from princomp in R

Tags: r, pca, variance, princomp

This should be very basic and I hope someone can help me.  I ran a principal component analysis with the following call:

```
pca <- princomp(....)
summary(pca)
```

Summary pca returns this description:

```
                          PC1    PC2     PC3
Standard deviation     2.8788 2.7862  2.1845
Proportion of Variance 0.1977 0.1549 0.07831
```

Look at the second line which shows the variance explained by each PC.  How can I programmatically extract this vector in my script from the variable pca.  I have done enough search and cannot find an answer.

Comment: Its calculated in the `print` method, and is not returned. Look at `stats:::print.summary.princomp` ti see where it is generated.

Answer (score 24):

Proportion of Variance is nothing else than normalized standard deviations. You can calculate them as `PoV <- pca$sdev^2/sum(pca$sdev^2)`

Answer (score 12):

Just:

```
summary(pc)$importance[2,]
```

Comment: And the cumulative proportions are in `summary(pc)$importance[3,]`